# AWS-LAMBDA PUPPETEER: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am trying to run Lambda function using lambda-puppeteer. I managed to to run Chrome from s3 bucket which I pass as a variable. But I am having this problem :

```
2018-10-08T12:20:47.679Z    952a7a67-caf4-11e8-8cce-f9cd0b7cb8b4    { MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params
at ParamValidator.fail (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:61:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
at ParamValidator.validate (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:125:42)
```

Can anyone please help me with this one. I also use claudiaJS to deploy.

Comment: Without looking at your code it seems that the error is pretty clear. When interacting with S3 objects you must provide both Key and Bucket.

Comment: I put chrome in a separate bucket.. But I have other problem now:
Task timed out...

Comment: Hi, is there any way to know what's inside the code :) ?

Comment: Often times this error comes up when you are hitting your bucket limit in your account, try deleting a couple of unused buckets and see if the error persists.

Comment: Check your `.env` variables, maybe you don't have the one referencing the bucket.